# How to enable modules (undo "Disable Modules Output") without admin access

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-1, adminhtml, configuration

i have just disabled some modules in magento. and i think we have disabled some important modules.
what i have done is:

> system > configuration > advanced > Disable Modules Output

i have disables every thing from there .the problem is now i can not access my admin panel. i have disabled some mage or important modules as well.

can some one tell me how to re-enable them from files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Disable module output" is a configuration, stored in the database, so you cannot change it from files, but with access to the database (MySQL console, phpMyAdmin, ...) you can undo it for all modules with the following query:

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'advanced/modules_disable_output/%'
```

or for only core modules:

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'advanced/modules_disable_output/Mage_%'
```

or for a specific module (in this example `Mage_Customer`):

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'advanced/modules_disable_output/Mage_Customer'
```