# What is solution for this after the disabling the extension my site is not loading css and js in frontend and admin area of magento

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I disabled an extension and now the CSS and JS is not loading anymore.

The extension documentation states:

> Don't try to disable the output of Fooman_Speedster under Configuration > Advanced - it will make your site unusable!

What can I do to recover?

Comment: `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` 

this should fix your issue.

Comment: To reenable module output, please refer to https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83738/how-to-enable-modules-undo-disable-modules-output-without-admin-access/83741#83741 and https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127064/disabled-mage-core/127066#127066 Note that you did not disable the extension, just hid all its blocks, which were rendering CSS and JS. To really disable it, edit `app/etc/modules/Fooman_Speedster.xml`

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to /app/etc/modules and rename the xml file of this module. 
2) Clear cache from backend. If backend is not working then delete the cache folder under /var/

Hope this'll help

Comment: If by "rename" you mean "delete", this should work ;) All XML files in app/etc/modules are processed, regardless of the name. Another solution would be to change `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>` in this file.

Comment: @FabianSchmengler hahaha You exactly know what i mean.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check by deploying the content again via static content deploy command.

If not than open cli(command line) and access root directory where your magento is installed and run below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Also remove var/generation and var/di folders and flush cache.

Comment: The question is tagged with "magento-1.9", where there is no static content deployment.

Comment: I was little busy while reply and didn't check the tags, so I replied in that way. Anyways.. Best of the luck if you can help him out on that.. :)